# SQL Server : group by, failing with expressions and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's consider I want to have `Users.image` and `Users.description` in the SQL statement as expressions, how do I add them in?

I get a error if I add `Users.image` into the SQL statement, and group by it.

This works:

```
SELECT 
    Users.username, COUNT(Topic.userid) AS upvotes
FROM 
    Users, Role, Topic, Vote, Topic_Vote
WHERE 
    Users.username = 'Adrian'
    AND Users.roleid = Role.roleid
    AND Topic.topicid = Topic_Vote.topicid
    AND Vote.voteid = Topic_Vote.voteid
    AND Topic.userid = Users.userid
GROUP BY 
    Users.username
```

This is what don't work:

```
SELECT 
    Users.username, Users.image, COUNT(Topic.userid) AS upvotes
FROM 
    Users, Role, Topic, Vote, Topic_Vote
WHERE 
    Users.username = 'Adrian'
    AND Users.roleid = Role.roleid
    AND Topic.topicid = Topic_Vote.topicid
    AND Vote.voteid = Topic_Vote.voteid
    AND Topic.userid = Users.userid
GROUP BY 
    Users.username, Users.image
```

Comment: Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  And why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Mr. Gordon Linoff, that is more a matter of preference. You don't need to use JOIN syntax.

Comment: Along with updating to using ANSI-92 syntax (it has been out for 27 years now) you should really be using `varchar(MAX)`, `nvarchar(MAX)` or `varbinary`. `(n)text` and `image` were deprecated in SQL Server 2005; and the use of them here is why you're getting an error.

Comment: @Adrian so the fact that they are no longer fully supported is a preference? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

Gordon is correct, there are many logical issues and limitations with the 'old style' join. 
I guess you are looking for something like the following - note that I didn't fix your original syntax,

```
WITH UserCounts AS
(
SELECT Users.username, COUNT(Topic.userid) as upvotes
FROM Users, Role, Topic, Vote, Topic_Vote
WHERE Users.username = 'Adrian'
AND Users.roleid = Role.roleid
AND Topic.topicid = Topic_Vote.topicid
AND Vote.voteid = Topic_Vote.voteid
AND Topic.userid = Users.userid
GROUP BY Users.username
)
SELECT UC.*, U.Image
FROM UserCounts AS UC INNER JOIN Users AS U ON UC.UserName = U.UserName
```